# How to append an array within a for loop that gets new outputs every loop?

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, append

I am trying to create a for loop that appends an array generated from a function that can only convert to an array. The following is the code:

```
array2 = np.array([])
for i in range(len(fps)):
    array1 = np.array([])
    DataStructs.ConvertToNumpyArray((fps[i]), array1)
    np.append(array1,array2)
    
array2
```

fps is a list of 634 elements, where each element has a length of 1024. The `DataStructs.ConvertToNumpyArray` function can only compute one entry at a time and stores the output in an array (array1 in the code above).
The following is an output for one entry (there are nonzero elements but within):

```
array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.])
```

How can I use a for loop to store all 634 elements in one array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
array2 = np.array([])
for i in range(len(fps)):
    array1 = np.array([])
    DataStructs.ConvertToNumpyArray((fps[i]), array1)

    # you need to assign the concatenated array to array2
    array2 = np.append(array2,array1)
    
array2



# if you want to have a 2D-array as output, you can do the following:

# initialize the array then assign new elements to it
array2 = np.zeros(shape=(len(fps),1024))
for i in range(len(fps)):
    array1 = np.array([])
    DataStructs.ConvertToNumpyArray((fps[i]), array1)
    array2[i] = array1
    
array2

# or you can use np.concatenate
array2 = np.zeros(shape=(0,1024))
for i in range(len(fps)):
    array1 = np.array([])
    DataStructs.ConvertToNumpyArray((fps[i]), array1)
    array2 = np.concatenate((array2,[array1]))
```

Comment: It worked but the issue is that it stored them into one as in:
array([0.,0.,0., ...., 0.,0.,0.]), how can I get it to be:
array([0.,0.,0., ...., 0.,0.,0.],[0.,0.,0., ...., 0.,0.,0.],....[0.,0.,0., ...., 0.,0.,0.])

Comment: I tried axis=0 in the append code, but that didn't do it.

Comment: @user16470918 you can use np.concatenate to get a 2d array.